# Getting the name of a parameter object

Tags: c#

I regularly have to export various List<> from within my code to external files. In order to do it in a generic way I wanted to write a function that just takes the name of my variable and then exports according to the fields in that class.

I have that working fine, the only thing what I can't seem to figure out is the name of the variable that I want to export. I can get the type of the class, but that's not what I need. I can get the name of the variable I put it into but that's not what I need either.

Below you'll find the code I'm using:

```
public class testClass
{
   public string firstName {get; set;}
   public string lastName {get; set;}
}    

private void test()
{
   testClass nameOfMyTestClass = new testClass();

   // DATA ADDED TO nameOfMyTestClass
   ...

   exportClass(nameOfMyTestClass);
}

public void exportClass(object selectedClass)
{
   string objectName = selectedClass.name;

   string output = string.Empty;

   // GET THE DATA FROM THE SETTINGS
   PropertyInfo[] properties = selectedClass.GetType().GetProperties();

   foreach (var p in properties)
   {
      output += "[" + p.Name + "] " + p.GetValue(selectedClass) + Environment.NewLine;
   }

   // WRITE THE FILE
   File.WriteAllText(basePath + @"DATA\" + objectName + ".txt", output, Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

So I'm passing the variable nameOfMyTestClass as an object into the method exportClass because I want to be able to use this for multiple different classes.

Inside that method I would like to use the name of the variable that I have added as the name of my file: e.g. nameOfMyTestClass.txt

I can get the Class itself by using the GetType() or I can use ToString() but that gives me NAMESPACE.Form1+testClass as a result but I can't find a way to get the actual name of the variable.

Does anybody have an idea how I can accomplish this?

Thanks

Comment: An object doesn't have a name. The name of the local variable just outside of a method that holds a reference to that object is by no means known to that object. You need to pass in the name as well, there's no way around it.

Comment: I completely agree with @LasseVågsætherKarlsen. The cleanest solution is to have a wrapper or object or make your objects be nameable. Although Loris' answer is also a possibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get variable names through reflection since they are not present in the compiled assembly's metadata.

But to get the name of the variable, you can use the `nameof()` operator (introduced with C# 6.0). Note that you would have to add an extra parameter for the name:

```
exportClass(nameOfMyTestClass, nameof(nameOfMyTestClass));

public void exportClass(object selectedClass, string name)
{ /* ... */ }
```

The advantage of the `nameof` operator is, that if you use refactoring (renaming), the passed name will be changed as well, compared to just passing the name in a string literal.

Comment: Thanks Adrian for your quick response.

Comment: @Cainnech note that your original code works fine to as long as you pass proper parameter - `exportClass(new {nameOfMyTestClass});`

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible because variables don't haves names after they are compiled to IL. But there is a Workaround for you:

```
void ExportClass(object obj, string className)
{
    ...
}

var testClass = new TestClass();
ExportClass(testClass, nameof(testClass));
```

You pass the variable name with `nameof` to the method and you can use it there.

Comment: I agree.. my answer will only work with Properties and not variables I will remove my answer